# Split NSString into NSArray by blank lines

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I am reading a *.srt subtitle file into a NSString. The content of this string looks like this:

```
1
00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:24,400
Altocumulus clouds occur between six thousand

2
00:00:24,600 --> 00:00:27,800
and twenty thousand feet above ground level.
```

I am looking for an elegant solution to split this string into an NSArray in which each element contains the information which is related to one particular subtitle-"frame", e.g. the zeroth element would look like this:

```
1
00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:24,400
Altocumulus clouds occur between six thousand
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this task in an elegant manner? I tried splitting the original string using the method

```
[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];
```

but this method fails to detect the blank lines..

Thanks for your help!

tobi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"]` doesn't work, then there are two possibilities:

1. Your file contains MSDOS-style line breaks, which are `\r\n`.  So try splitting on `@"\r\n\r\n"`.
2. Your supposedly blank lines contain spaces or tabs.  You can check this from the shell using `cat -e`.

Comment: Splitting by "\r\n\r\n" did the job! Thank you so much!

Comment: @tobias.henn when an answer works, it is the general practice to accept that answer.

Comment: Hi Richard, I was not aware of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `NSScanner` instead. It's more flexible and you don't have to worry about whether your line breaks are Windows or Unix style and whether the blank lines contain any spaces. Here's an example:

```
NSMutableArray *lines = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *s = @"foo\n\nbar\r\n  \t  \r\nbaz"; //intentionally mixed line breaks
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:NULL];
    NSString *line = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&line];
    if (line) {
        [lines addObject:line];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", lines);
```

Comment: I am going to looking into NSScanners this evening! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip, the line breaks are a CRLF, which would be `\r\n`.